# pandas categorical remove categories from multiple columns

Tags: pandas, list-comprehension

I have many categorical columns like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "category1": [" ",
                      "data",
                      "more data",
                      "         "],
        "category2": ["   ", "more data", " ", "and more"],
    }
)
df["category1"] = df["category1"].astype("category")
df["category2"] = df["category2"].astype("category")
```

I want to remove any levels of the categorical type columns that only have whitespace, while ensuring they remain categories (can't use `.str` in other words). I have tried:

```
cat_cols = df.select_dtypes("category").columns
for c in cat_cols:
    levels = [level for level in df[c].cat.categories.values.tolist()
              if level.isspace()]
    df[c] = df[c].cat.remove_categories(levels)
```

This works, so I tried making it faster and neater with list-comprehension like so:

```
df[cat_cols] = [df[c].cat.remove_categories(
                [level for level in df[c].cat.categories.values.tolist()
                if level.isspace()])
                for c in cat_cols]
```

At which point I get "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"

Note, I don't want to use `inplace` parameter in the list-comp because it is going to be deprecated for `pd.Categorical`.

Feel like I might be missing something basic here, but how do I do this with a list-comprehension and not use `inplace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df[cat_cols] = pd.DataFrame({c: df[c].cat.remove_categories(
                [level for level in df[c].cat.categories.values.tolist()
                if level.isspace()])
                for c in cat_cols})

print (df)
   id  category1  category2
0   1        NaN        NaN
1   2       data  more data
2   3  more data        NaN
3   4        NaN   and more
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df[cat_cols] = pd.concat([df[c].cat.remove_categories(
                [level for level in df[c].cat.categories.values.tolist()
                if level.isspace()])
                for c in cat_cols], axis=1)

print (df)
   id  category1  category2
0   1        NaN        NaN
1   2       data  more data
2   3  more data        NaN
3   4        NaN   and more
```